# Liferay renderURLParams

Tags: java, jsp, liferay-6

i'm trying to create a hook from document_library for search only folders.

I'm using only two jsp pages: toolbar.jsp and search_resources.jsp

I added a checkbox input in the form of toolbar.jsp:

```
<c:if test="<%= showFoldersSearch %>">
    <aui:nav-bar-search cssClass="pull-right">
        <div class="form-search">
            <liferay-portlet:resourceURL varImpl="searchURL">
                <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/document_library/search" />
                <portlet:param name="repositoryId" value="<%= String.valueOf(repositoryId) %>" />
                <portlet:param name="searchRepositoryId" value="<%= String.valueOf(folderId) %>" />
                <portlet:param name="folderId" value="<%= String.valueOf(folderId) %>" />
                <portlet:param name="searchFolderId" value="<%= String.valueOf(folderId) %>" />
            </liferay-portlet:resourceURL>

            <aui:form action="<%= searchURL.toString() %>" method="get" name="fm1" onSubmit="event.preventDefault();">
                <liferay-portlet:renderURLParams varImpl="searchURL" />
                <aui:input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="<%= currentURL %>" />
                <aui:input name="breadcrumbsFolderId" type="hidden" value="<%= folderId %>" />
                <aui:input name="searchFolderIds" type="hidden" value="<%= folderId %>" />
                <aui:input name="onlyFolders" type="checkbox" value="0" label="Only folders" onChange="toggleCheckboxValue(this)" />
                <liferay-ui:input-search />
            </aui:form>
        </div>
    </aui:nav-bar-search>
</c:if>
```

And added a js function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleCheckboxValue(element) {
    if(element.checked) {
        element.value = "1";
    } else {
        element.value = "0";
    }
}
```

In search_resources.jsp i'm getting the boolean input using:

Boolean onlyFolders = ParamUtil.getBoolean(request, "onlyFoldersCheckbox");

But i never get the correct value from the checkbox.
Even if i list all the request parameters i have not the 3 parameters passed by renderURLParams.

```
System.out.println("Request parameters");
System.out.println("----");
java.util.Enumeration<String> en = request.getParameterNames();
while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
    String value = "";
    value = en.nextElement();
    System.out.println(value  + "   " + request.getParameter(value));
}
```

prints the following:

```
Request parameters
----
viewEntries   1
viewFolders   1
keywords   
folderStart   0
searchRepositoryId   10182
searchType   1
folderEnd   20
repositoryId   10182
folderId   0
entryStart   0
displayStyle   
entryEnd   20
showRepositoryTabs   1
struts_action   /document_library/search
searchFolderId   0
showSearchInfo   1
```

No variables from liferay-portlet:renderURLParams has been listed.

Where can i get the value of onlyFolders? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If a checkbox isn't checked its value won't be submitted.  I would suggest adding a hidden field.  Give it a default value of 0.  Then use your Javascript method to toggle its value back and forth between 0 and 1.